# Using Spring XD 1.2.1 with Flo - Not seeing "create stream" under Streams tab

Tags: spring-xd

I'm trying to use the Flo UI in Spring XD 1.2.1.  All of the tutorials/videos I've seen show a "create stream" tab. Video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=17pLpcdIu_M  shows what I'm referring to.

However, in my environment this tab does not exist. I can create a stream via the Spring XD shell but I want to try with Flo UI. Any ideas??

Comment: grammar corrections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the UI jar in `/xd/lib` with the flo-enabled one; see the [links on the project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/).